# DAG started from airflow scheduler not finding values in airflow.cfg

Tags: airflow

I'm taking advantage of the fact that Airflow v1.7.1.3 provides access to `airflow.cfg` to place some configuration values there rather than embedded in the code. We added the following as the first lines of the `airflow.cfg` file:

```
[foo]
bar = foo
      bar
```

In the `foobarDAG.py` class representing the DAG, I do the following:

```
from airflow.configuration import conf
…
def fooBar():
    pass

foobarList = conf['foo']['bar'].split('\n')

foobarOperator = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fooBar',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=fooBar,
    op_args=[foobarList],
    dag=dag)
```

Testing this manually from the Python prompt is easy:

```
>>> from foobarDAG import foobarList
…
>>> foobarList
['foo', 'bar']
```

That's just what I would expect from the information in `airflow.cfg`, above.

We've also performed a test on the DAG directly:

```
airflow test foobarDAG fooBar 10-19-2016
```

That doesn't report any problems.

The problem crops up when we try to use the scheduler to schedule that one DAG:

```
airflow scheduler -d foobarDAG >& foobar_log.txt
```

In the web UI, we see the following at the top of the "DAGS" section:

```
Broken DAG: [/path/to/…/foobarDAG.py] 'foo'
```

And in `foobar_log.txt`, here is the error message:

```
[2016-10-19 14:56:09,028] {models.py:250} ERROR - Failed to import: /path/to/foobarDAG.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/airflow/models.py", line 247, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/foobarenv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/to/foobarDAG.py", line 67, in <module>
    foobarList = conf['foo']['bar'].split('\n')
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/foobarenv/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 956, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'foo'
```

So oddly it appears that the scheduler isn't retrieving the `['foo']` section from `airflow.cfg` and providing it to the DAG. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that everything was working properly, but the scheduler hadn't been restarted. The scheduler was apparently still using the old `airflow.cfg` which did not have the added section.